# Regular Expression : At least one letter, At least one number, Certain length And Does not include

Tags: regex, groovy

I am using regular expressions with Groovy.

I am trying to formulate a regular expression with the following rules.

1. Must be exactly 17 characters
2. Must only contain letters and numbers
3. Must contain at least 1 alpha and 1 numeric character
4. Cannot contain the letters ‘I’, ‘O’ or ‘Q’ (Upper or Lowercase)

With the expression below I think I am almost there. The regular expression below seems to take care of requirement 1,2 and 3.

```
 def pttrnVin = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+){17}$/
```

I've tried to add in requirement 4 but am having no success. Could someone please help me with that?

thanks

Comment: change `a-z` to `a-hj-npr-z` *(use a case insensitive flag to not have to repeat the same in uppercase)* and remove the `+` quantifier and the capture group that are useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Must be exactly 17 characters. (Handled below)
2. Must only contain letters and numbers.  (Handled below)
3. Must contain at least 1 alpha and 1 numeric character. `(?=.*[0-9])(?=[a-z])`
4. Cannot contain the letters ‘I’, ‘O’ or ‘Q’ (Upper or Lowercase) `([a-hj-npr-z0-9]{17})`

So:

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-hj-npr-z0-9]{17})$/i
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cVz4b9/4/)

Comment: That doesn't quite seem to work. I changed your test to use '1234QDeEfFgGhHiII' for example and also 1234qDeEfFgGhHiII and it still matches